# generating QR Code for text in Indic language, hindi

Tags: qr-code, zxing

I need to generate QR code for a string that is in Hindi, an Indian language. I am using a Firefox Addon, QR Code Image Generator 2.0.1 and typing in Hindi using Ibus in Ubuntu and it is generating a QR Code but when I try to scan it using the Barcode Scanner app by zxing, it doesnt get recognized. I had raised [this issue](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/issues/231) in github repo of zxing but it seems I need to use something called ECI segment, something I didnt understand. Can somebody tell me what I need to do so that QR Code when scanned can be detected as Hindi text and the same is displayed.

Comment: What's the exact text that you're trying to encode?

Comment: "माना ये किताब आपका हॆ, इस किताब कि परछाई किसकी हॆ?" This is the text in [hindi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug with the Firefox plugin you're using.  It's perfectly possible to create a QR code with Hindi text:

[image]

If you take a look at the technical details of the QR code at http://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx you'll see that the ECI segment has been set to UTF-8.